# moc-ed files being excluded from build in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt-vs-addin

I have a VS2010 solution with couple of Qt-based projects. Every time when i modify files from one certain project, generated files (moc_*.cpp ones) changes its properties to be excluded from build. Checked all the available properties but couldn't find anything related to the issue (didn't tried to recreate the project from scratch though).

Any chances to fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200268/qt4-in-visual-studio-2008-moc-ed-files-get-excluded-from-build).

First you have to check the MocDirectory in the Qt Project Settings.
Originally, I set it to the wrong value $(Configuration) and encountered the same problem as you.

After I changed it to $(ConfigurationName), the problem disappeared.

The reason that when the wrong value is set, MocDirectory points to the same directory for different project configuration (e.g. debug and release). When the project is built, it will excluded the generated files in MocDirectory with respect to other project configurations. Since all the configurations refer to the same MocDirectory, all generated files will be excluded.

Comment: Thanks, i've seen things like you describe before and i thougnt i've checked it (can't be sure for now). Fixed by recreating project and adding files. Also, i should've find that related question by myself, my bad.