# Moc'ed file gets mysteriously excluded from Visual Studio project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qt-vs-addin

I have several Visual Studio projects created with the Qt Visual Studio Tools (always the latest version available at the moment of the project creation, some dating from the first versions supporting Qt 5, now is the 2.2.1). All projects are compiled with VS 2010, although the IDE is VS 2017 (15.7.4 so far).

From some time on, some projects started to report link errors such as

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const MyQtClass::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@MyQtClass@@2UQMetaObject@@B)

For this example, `MyQtClass.h` file declares `MyQtClass` and has the `Q_OBJECT` macro. `MyQtClass.cpp` defines the methods.

After a quick inspection, I discovered that the problem came from fact that the associated moc'ed file (`moc_MyQtClass.cpp` for above example) was *excluded* from compilation for current configuration. Here the extract of the .vcxproj file:

```
<ClCompile Include="GeneratedFiles\Debug\moc_MyQtClass.cpp">
  <ExcludedFromBuild Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">true</ExcludedFromBuild>
  <ExcludedFromBuild Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">true</ExcludedFromBuild>
</ClCompile>
<ClCompile Include="GeneratedFiles\Release\moc_MyQtClass.cpp">
  <ExcludedFromBuild Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">true</ExcludedFromBuild>
</ClCompile>
```

If I modify the .vcxproj file to remove the exclusion from the Debug configuration, then the project works.

The problem only happens when the *main* .cpp file associated to the `Q_OBJECT`ed class is modified (`MyQtClass.cpp` in my example). At the time such file is saved, the .vcxproj file is modified with the exclusions.

This issue doesn't appears in every Qt project I have, but once it starts it keeps appearing every time the associated .cpp file is modified. I haven't been able to discover a pattern for it. In addition, it happens in several development systems at the company, so it doesn't seem to be a problem of my computer.

The only workaround I've found is to discard the changes from the project file, but it is a headache to be discarding and relaunching the project *every time* those files are modified (which happens to be a *lot* of times).

Has anybody experienced the same issue? Any ideas how to solve it?

---

Update: the issue only happens when the modified file is the .cpp file with identical basename regarding the header file (`MyQtClass.cpp` in my example). If I modified another file that also defines more methods of the `MyQtClass` class (such as `MyQtClass_more_definitions.cpp`), no error is given.

---

As it seems to be a bug in the Qt Visual Studio Tools with no workaround, I've reported it under [QTVSADDINBUG-555](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTVSADDINBUG-555).

Comment: have your tried Full Rebuild (after clean)?

Comment: @DanM. Yes, the problem is that the project file is modified when the .cpp file is saved: subsequent builds, cleans, rebuilds do nothing.

Comment: do you build in Debug? Does it build in Release? I wonder why it excludes both Release and Debug mocs in Debug and only Debug in Release (as it probably should). Also, there is a chance you'll receive help faster if you try and ask this on qt forums directly. Maybe it's a bug in a new extension.

Comment: @DanM. If build in Debug (and the issue occurs) just fails in Debug, but when working in Release it may happen too.

Comment: seems related/duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28455525/qt-vs-addin-obj-files-are-not-generated-for-moc-cpp-files or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941885/moc-ed-files-being-exluded-from-build-in-visual-studio-2010 (though it doesn't look like there was a definite solution to the 1st one)

Comment: @DanM. seems to be very similar (probably the same issue although no information about versions is given), but unfortunately no valid answers are given :(

Comment: @buchart, just to be sure: the project was created with the latest (2.2.0+) version of Qt Add-in? Same problem with 2.2.1. But yeah, I'm out of ideas. Maybe folks on Qt forums can help: https://forum.qt.io/

Comment: @DanM. thanks for your help, the second question didn't help neither (actually, it was already applied). And sorry, yes, plugin is 2.2.1. I'll refer directly to plugin's project page and post the solution here (if any). Thanks again!

Comment: @DanM. I was discussing with the plugin's team and got a solution (with some tweaks), in case you were interested in this issue

Comment: Thanks. Nice knowing you've sorted this out. Was this some bug in the plugin or some problem with configuration? Will it be fixed in future versions?

Comment: @DanM. It seems to be a known issue (or at least related to other ones), but no more information was given. On the other hand, custom build steps are on their way to be deprecated by Qt VS Tools in favor of MSBuild, so I'm not sure if it's going to be fixed

Comment: Ah, OK. I thought latest addin already used MSBuild instead of custom steps.

Comment: @DanM. yes it does... for new projects, old ones are not automatically migrated, that was my case... and even though, migration can create new issues to be solved (see the answer for more detail).

Comment: That explains it. I though you answered positively to mu previous question regarding the version of Addin that was used to create the project, but I now see that you were only replying to the second part of the question, hence my confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After discussing it with the Qt VS Tools team, I managed to solve the problem. I've tested it using the latest version of the plugin currently available (2.2.1).

Solution consisted in converting the custom build steps into Qt/MSBuild commands (more about it [here](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2018/02/16/qt-visual-studio-improving-performance/)). To do so I used the menu option *Qt VS Tools / Convert custom build steps to Qt/MSBuild*.

After conversion, I had to deal with some issue tough. I document them here:

- I had to remove all header files with the `Q_OBJECT` macro and re-add them manually in order to be able to moc'ed them (I also removed/re-added all .ui files, not sure if influenced in anyway).
- Precompiled headers setting (using PCH) was not respected when adding existing files (.h with `Q_OBJECT`). Files were added through drag&drop. If I switched PCH off and then on it work for already added files, new ones still needed manual intervention (PCH off/on or editing the `.vcxproj` as shown below).

  Invalid entry in `.vcxproj`:

  ```
  <QtMoc Include="new_file_added.h" />
  ```

  Changed to:

  ```
  <QtMoc Include="example.h">
    <ForceInclude Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">StdAfx.h;../../%(Filename)%(Extension)</ForceInclude>
    <ForceInclude Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">StdAfx.h;../../%(Filename)%(Extension)</ForceInclude>
  </QtMoc>
  ```

  Another way to solve it is to open the properties of the affected header file and change *Qt Meta-Object Compiler / Force Include* option to `StdAfx.h;../../%(Filename)%(Extension)` (change `StdAfx.h` with your PCH filename if different):

  [image: header file properties]
- I had some QRC files being compiled to a binary file. The binary output was set for every QRC file by default. I had to change the global property to `false` to solve it:

  ```
  <QtRcc>
    <BinaryOutput>false</BinaryOutput>
  </QtRcc>
  ```

  Or using .qrc properties:

  [image: QRC properties]

  Also, output files for them were C++ sources (`qrc_*.cpp`, instead of the output name in the original project, `*.rcc`). Just change set the `DynamicSource` to `false` and the`OutputFile` elements in the corresponding `ItemGroup`s:

  ```
  <ItemGroup>
    <QtRcc Include="resources\resources.qrc">
      <BinaryOutput>true</BinaryOutput>
      <DynamicSource>false</DynamicSource>
      <OutputFile>$(SolutionDir)\output\resources.rcc</OutputFile>
    </QtRcc>
  </ItemGroup>
  ```

  Or using the GUI:
  [image: DynamicSource]

After those changes it worked perfectly (in my two environments, VS 2010 and VS 2017).

PS: It seems to be a known issue (or at least related to other ones), but no more information was given. On the other hand, custom build steps are on their way to be deprecated by Qt VS Tools in favor of MSBuild, so I'm not sure if it's going to be fixed.

Comment: All I had to do in my case was remove and re-add the header.  It was working in Debug but not Release, and the project had been "upgraded" on import - something got missed along the way it seems.

Comment: @Clifford that also happened to me, but after a _while_ (undetermined) it happened again, and again...